# Aggregate array of custom type along one of its variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom type:

```
Private Type invoiceLine
    itemCode As String
    packageSize As String
    englishName As String
    boxName As String
    weight As Double
    pieces As Double
End Type
```

I want to sum weight and pieces to get the sum for each unique itemCode.

Example:
I have items with

```
itemCode=1564, weight=2, pieces=3
itemCode=1564, weight=1, pieces=1
itemCode=1564, weight=3, pieces=1
itemCode=3333, weight=2, pieces=4
```

I want ot aggregate this to get:

```
itemCode=1564, weight=6, pieces=5
itemCode=3333, weight=2, pieces=4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Probably can do this using a dictionary object and iterating your array. Give me a minute I will work an example...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a dictionary object.

```
Private Type InvoiceLine
    itemCode As String
    packageSize As String
    englishName As String
    boxName As String
    weight As Double
    pieces As Double
End Type

Sub Test()
Dim invoices() As InvoiceLine
Dim dict As Object ' we will use a scripting dictionary to compute your aggregation
Dim wt As Double, pcs As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim itm As Variant

ReDim invoices(4)

'#### INITIALIZE SOME DUMMY DATA ####
invoices(0).itemCode = 1
invoices(1).itemCode = 2
invoices(2).itemCode = 1
invoices(3).itemCode = 1
invoices(4).itemCode = 3

invoices(0).pieces = 3
invoices(1).pieces = 2
invoices(2).pieces = 5
invoices(3).pieces = 4
invoices(4).pieces = 7

invoices(0).weight = 100
invoices(1).weight = 200
invoices(2).weight = 59
invoices(3).weight = 43
invoices(4).weight = 77

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = LBound(invoices) To UBound(invoices)
    wt = invoices(i).weight
    pcs = invoices(i).pieces
    If dict.Exists(invoices(i).itemCode) Then
        'Update the dictionary Value for this entry
        wt = wt + dict(invoices(i).itemCode)(0)
        pcs = pcs + dict(invoices(i).itemCode)(1)

    End If
    'Add this item to the dictionary
     dict(invoices(i).itemCode) = Array(wt, pcs)

Next

For Each itm In dict.Keys()

    MsgBox "Item #: " & itm & vbCrLf & _
           "Weight: " & dict(itm)(0) & vbCrLf & _
           "Pieces: " & dict(itm)(1)


Next

End Sub
```